# Python read strings from file, preserving variables to be printed

Tags: python, string, list, file-io

I am making a Python script that will choose a response at random from a list.

To fill this list I want to read strings from a file, the strings will look something like this:

```
"This number is " + str(num) + ", this is good"
"Oh no the number is " + str(num) +", this is good
```

Obviously these are read from the file as strings so if I printed one of them they would come out as you see them here and wont have the value for "num" substituted. Is there anyway to read these strings from a file while keeping the ability to substitute variables (like a raw format) like how it would work if my code did

```
list.append("This number is " + str(num) + ", this is good")
```

The reason I want to read from a file is because I will have many different strings and they may change so I would rather not hard code them into the program (keep in mind the example strings are very basic)

Thanks

Comment: could you show your code and explain what is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec), and then call `.format` on your strings before displaying them.

strings.txt:

```
This number is {num} this is good
Oh no the number is {num} this is good
```

main.py:

```
import random

with open("strings.txt") as file:
    possible_strings = file.read().split("\n")

number = 23

s = random.choice(possible_strings)
print(s.format(num=number))
```

Possible output:

```
This number is 23 this is good
```

Comment: Right ok so format() is kinda like a "search and replace" function?

Answer (score 1):

Use something in your file to indicate a substitution is needed, and then make those substitutions.

For example, if you need to put in the value of `num`, your text could use `{{num}}` where the substitution is needed.  Then use regex to find such substrings, and replace them with the desired values.

Comment: Oh of course this has been a case of going about it the wrong way, how silly of me. I could pick a string then do what you mentioned

Comment: Seems like overkill to use regex when Python already has two different value-substituting string methods: `.format` and the percent operator